# ConvertTo-SecureString - Key not valid for use in specified state After Reboot

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a Powershell script that's been running from months using a password stored as a secure string in a file. When I went to run the script today I started receiving the "Key not valid for use in specified state". The script is invoked by a scheduled task run by an active directory domain account. The account didn't change, and the only event I'm aware of was a server reboot. What could cause this issue to happen?

Converting my data back into a secure string again resolved the issue, but I'm puzzled as to why it happened in the first place.

I create the password file via:

```
Write-Host "Please enter the filename where you'd like to store the password:"
$passwordFile = Read-Host
Write-Host "Please enter the ftp password and press enter:"
read-host -AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File $passwordFile
Write-Host "Your Password File ($passwordFile) has been created."
```

I retrieve the password from the file like so:

```
$FTPPassword = Get-Content $FTPPasswordFilePath
$script:FTPCredObj = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $FTPUserName,($FTPPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString)
```

I did notice errors in the event log pertaining to the user profile:

"Windows cannot find the local profile and is logging you on with a temporary profile. Changes you make to this profile will be lost when you log off."

I did RDP in as the task user to update the file containing the secure string, and I didn't notice any profile errors after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're logged on with a temporary profile, you don't have access to resources that live in your profile.  This will include the encryption key that is used to encrypt and decrypt PowerShell secure strings.

So the underlying problem is whatever is causing your profile to fail to load.  (That's not a programming issue, so you should talk to your system administrators - or if that's you, you could ask over at Super User or Server Fault.)

Note that the problem will recur the next time you log out and back in, because you've now encrypted the password with a key that is only stored in the temporary profile, which will be discarded when you log out.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. I RDP'd to the box as the task user and noticed that two users were logged in, and I had to forcibly disconnect one. I didn't see a user profile error associated with this login. Could two users accessing RDP prevent a task user from accessing it's profile?

Comment: @Barnes: not on a fully functioning system.